# How to hide a jButton Event method in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, events, netbeans, jframe

I'm programming with NetBeans using Java to create a GUI interface based on JFrame. In the JFrame I have a jButton  and I had created an event for this button which is mouseClicked.

But now I would like to delete this event(& remove it's corresponding method) and can't find a way to do so.

Can you help please ?

Comment: If you wish to remove *mouseClicked* handler then select Button + Properties + Event Tab + Remove the name of handler from Event properties.

Comment: I hope you intend to add an `ActionLListener` once the `MouseListener` is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unregister the mouse listener at run time you can use [removeMouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#removeMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29) method of JButton that it inherits from Component class. You may also need to remove [mouse motion listene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#removeMouseMotionListener%28java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener%29)r and [mouse wheel listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#removeMouseWheelListener%28java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener%29) if you have added them to the button.

And if you are talking about finding the related code in NetBeans and deleting that code then follow the steps:

1. Open *Design view* of form.
2. Click on the button, you want to remove listeners from.
3. In the *Properties* view, go to *Events* tab.
4. Remove the mouse events. (ie. *mouseClicked, mouseMoved, mousePressed, .....*)

Comment: thanks :) all i needed was the second and the steps  paragraph & sorry for being late but I have a project to do/finished now :-D

Answer (score 1):

for [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) you can :

- [JButtons#etEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)
- [JButton#setVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)

Comment: I think *OP* wants to *delete* the event handler.

Comment: @AVD are we supply GUI framewors guide ???, just for fun convert your comment to answer, amybe you are right :-)